# how to emit a http request for java (and handle the response)

Tags: java, php, get, send

I have a little trouble with an application in java

I have to send some information (key within) with my android application to a PHP file (register.php).
Then generate a password with the key in the PHP script.
And my java application gets the password.

First, i try to pass the java key to my PHP and get it.

**But when I do this, i receive this result:**

```
 <br /><font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error xe-notice' dir='ltr' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'><tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size: x-large;'>( ! )</span> 
Notice: Use of undefined constant FirstName - assumed 'FirstName' in C:\wamp64\www\Register.php on line <i>16</i></th></tr><tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#e9b96e' colspan='5'>Call Stack</th></tr><tr><th align='center' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>#</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Time</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Memory</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Function</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Location</th></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>1</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0006</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>367320</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>{main}(  )</td><td title='C:\wamp64\www\Register.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>...\Register.php<b>:</b>0</td></tr></table></font><br /><font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error xe-notice' dir='ltr' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'><tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size: x-large;'>( ! )</span> Notice: Use of undefined constant LastName - assumed 'LastName' in C:\wamp64\www\Register.php on line <i>17</i></th></tr><tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#e9b96e' colspan='5'>Call Stack</th></tr><tr><th align='center' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>#</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Time</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Memory</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Function</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Location</th></tr><tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>1</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0006</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>367320</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>{main}(  )</td><td title='C:\wamp64\www\Register.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>...\Register.php<b>:</b>0</td></tr></table></font><br /><font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error xe-notice' dir='ltr' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'><tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size: x-large;'>( ! )</span> Notice: Use of undefined constant Reason - assumed 'Reason' in C:\wamp64\www\Register.php on line <i>18</i></th></tr><tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#e9b96e' colspan='5'>Call Stack</th></tr><tr><th align='center' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>#</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Time</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Memory</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Function</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Location</th></tr><tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>1</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0006</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>367320</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>{main}(  )</td><td title='C:\wamp64\www\Register.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>...\Register.php<b>:</b>0</td></tr></table></font><br /><font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error xe-notice' dir='ltr' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'><tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size: x-large;'>( ! )</span> Notice: Use of undefined constant Key - assumed 'Key' in C:\wamp64\www\Register.php on line <i>19</i></th></tr><tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#e9b96e' colspan='5'>Call Stack</th></tr><tr><th align='center' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>#</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Time</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Memory</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Function</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Location</th></tr><tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>1</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0006</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>367320</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>{main}(  )</td><td title='C:\wamp64\www\Register.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>...\Register.php<b>:</b>0</td></tr></table></font><br /><font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error xe-notice' dir='ltr' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'><tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span style='background-color: #cc0
```

My program takes all the echo of the PHP page, and I know what the problem. The reader success to read all the echo line, but it read this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bvEgm.png)

Between the time I post the information to my PHP, and the time I get the information from my PHP, informations are lost. Maybe because the page is charging when I go to the get.

**Here is my code Java**

---

```
Context context;
        BackgroundTask(Context ctx)
        {
            this.context = ctx;
        }
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

protected String Password;

public String getpassword()
{
    return Password;
}


@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String RegistrationUrl = "http://myip:port/register.php";
    String method = params[0];
    String FirstName = params[1];
    String LastName = params[2];
    String Reason = params[3];
    String Key = params[4];






    try {
        URL url = new URL(RegistrationUrl);
        HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        OutputStream Os = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
        BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(Os, "UTF-8"));
        String Data = URLEncoder.encode("FirstName", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(FirstName, "UTF-8") + "&"
                + URLEncoder.encode("LastName", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(LastName, "UTF-8") + "&"
                + URLEncoder.encode("Reason", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(Reason, "UTF-8") + "&"
                + URLEncoder.encode("Key", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(Key, "UTF-8");

        bufferedWriter.write(Data);
        InputStream IS = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpURLConnection.getInputStream()));

        String line;
        String result ="";
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            result = result + line;
        }
       Password = result;
        bufferedWriter.flush();
        bufferedWriter.close();
        Os.close();
     bufferedReader.close();
      IS.close();
      httpURLConnection.disconnect();

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    } catch (ProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }

return Password;
}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
    super.onProgressUpdate(values);
}


@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    Toast.makeText(context, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
}
```

---

**And my PHP code**

---

```
    <?php require "connection.php";

$FirstName = $_POST[FirstName];
 $LastName = $_POST[LastName];
 $Reason = $_POST[Reason];
 $Key = $_POST[Key];

$mysql_qry = "INSERT INTO requesttable(FirstName, LastName, Reason) VALUES ('$FirstName', '$LastName', '$reason')";


if($conn->query($mysql_qry) === TRUE)
{
    echo $Key;
}
else
{
    echo "error: ".$mysql_qry ."<br>". $conn->error; 
}
?>
```

---

I searched on the net, but I don't find a lot about that. I have somes difficulties with Java and PHP

Thanks for your help

Comment: First of all, please go read [ask]. We expect you to show all code relevant to your problem in text form directly inside your question, properly formatted - do not just show images _of_ code.

Comment: Oh...ok, sorry about that, first time.

Comment: Please recognise you seem to have 2 questions - 1) how to emit a http request for java (and handle the response) 2) how to accept a post request (and generate a response). You'll have greater success if you treat them as literally 2 questions - and start with the second one. I'm sure both of these questions have been asked many, many times before.

Comment: Question still has references to code-as-images and paraphrased error message (`use of undefined content.`). Please include the error message verbatim (in addition to considering my prior comment).

Comment: Thanks you for the advice, i will change my question

Comment: Please copy and paste the error text into the question - it is _still_ wrong. If you don't read the error messages - how do you expect anyone else to :)?

Comment: I red the error message, but it just the description of the picture below. 

I add the error message to the question.

Answer (score -1):

I would put those $_POST['variableNames'] in single/double quotes, as you are using constants FirstName, LastName etc. which you have not predefined, that`s why your $_POST values are lost, as they are not being assigned to a php variables.

```
$FirstName = "";
if(isset($_POST['FirstName']){
$FirstName = $_POST['FirstName'];
} else {
 //some errror
}
```

Otherwise to use constants which I seem unnecessary define those constants first:

```
define("FirstName", "FirstName");
$FirstName = $_POST[FirstName];
```

To prevent errors/warnings from php response use error_reporting(0) at top of php page (for example if php gives output for depricated functions etc.)

Comment: `To prevent errors/warnings from php response use error_reporting(0) at top of php page` - this is bad advice, especially in the context of the question - the right action is to fix the cause of the warnings.

Comment: Of course you have to fix error in first place - but yet, the main question is why this is happening (the warning appears) - and it appears to me I answered it with the code provided and explanation, more of it I gave a tip how to prevent php output from warnings, for example if some function will be depricated in future php versions - if there is anything to say, you should say it, not the case ... and second, then maybe we should start answering all stack questions with "you have to fix cause of an error/warning then everything will be OK man." - if this is what you suggest to author! :D

Comment: `Of course you have to fix error in first place ` - please edit the answer to actually say that, to indicate what the error means, to show and explain how to avoid that and only then if you wish to add any other helpful hints. The answer is currently implicit in the code - make it explicit using words :).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I use the post isset. But strangely, i still have the error message (only with the application, i have nothing when i start directly the php).

Comment: Also, the probleme is not the error message. Error message appaired because my data are cleared between two operation. So, if a send a key to take a password:
- My application will send the key
- Php will generate the password
- My application will recall the php....and cleared all
- My application will take....an empty password.

This is why i have an error "undefined variable", and i would like to keep the  value i send when i take values from php.